# Transferring Entire Account Balance with XCM and Calculating Required Deposits: Best Practices

Tags: xcm, teleport

Is it possible to transfer the entire balance of an account using XCM, similar to the 'transferAll' function, considering the required deposit for XCM in each transaction?

Another question is, what is the best practice for calculating the required deposit before sending a message/transaction?